# Need a Free Trial of MOSS 2007 VM

Tags: download, virtual-machine, trial-version

I need MOSS 2007 VM very badly for some testing. The current blogs are pointing to an MS link which is no longer working. Can anyone please let me know from where I can download a free trial of MOSS 2007 VM? I am building an application which needs to be tested for compatibility with MOSS 2007. Please help.

Comment: You can still download MOSS from MSDN assuming you have a subscription...

Comment: I need the complete VM not just MOSS 2007 installer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build a Virtual Machine using Hyper-V

Here is the download link for SP2007

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8550

Comment: I honestly don't want to spend time on building a complete VM on my own. This is intended mainly for some testing purposes.

Comment: It won't take more than an hour to built it.. It's very hard to get a trial version of 2007.. Most might have already expired 180 days